# how to be notified of a program execution in linux

Tags: linux, execution, inotify

There is an **inotifywait** program from inotify-tools, which helps to detect creation, modification, opening and so on of watched files or directories, but there is no distinct **"executed"** event. I also have tried **fileschanged** utility, but it seems that although "created" and "modified" events work, "executed" does not. Is there a way to be notified on execution of selected programs or programs in selected directory?

My problem is that although I can monitor "executed" action on binaries with "OPEN" inotify event, I need to compute checksum of that binary so it would be another "OPEN" action and it brings me to infinite recursion. Of course I can use inotifywait in a loop and every time get a single action rather than to use monitor mode, but then there is a chance that some events would be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no event in inotify to do what you want exactly. I'm not sure if this is feasible for your situation, but one thing you could try to avoid your recursion problem with "open" is to use the IN_ONESHOT option, then calculate your checksum and re-call inotify on the binary that triggered it in the same script.

Comment: Yes, it seems that using C interface to inotify is the only way to achieve my goal, but the question about notification on execution is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install [sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/), you can monitor executions based on the command name:

```
sudo sysdig "proc.name=foobar and evt.type=execve"
```